# Upload Files To Site

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-web-app-service

I am getting failures trying to upload and download FTP files to an Azure website.  I used both an FTP client and I tried using the WebClient class.  Both failed to upload or download FTP files.  Some of what I tried:

- I tested both port 20 and 21 with the FTP software client.  Neither connected.
- I changed the credentials twice and waited ten minutes each time.  Still failed.
- I deleted everything and started again.
- I set the WebClient proxy property to NULL, still failed.  I removed this property and it still failed.  I had seen some info about a requirement of this property being null for FTP servers; not sure if that's accurate though.
- Credentials were set using the Network Credential class.
- NET code => http://searchwindowsserver.techtarget.com/tip/Use-a-PowerShell-FTP-script-to-upload-and-download-files

```
param($Username,$Password,$FilePath,$ServerName,$Action)
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($UserName, $Password)

$file = Get-Item -Path $FilePath
$uri = New-Object System.Uri(“ftp://$ServerName/$($file.Name)”)

if ($Action -eq ‘Download’) {
    $webclient.DownloadFile($uri, $FilePath)
} elseif ($Action -eq ‘Upload’) {
    $webclient.UploadFile($uri, $FilePath)
}
```

In general, most articles on this seem to be from a year ago and most recent articles show screenshots that no longer exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See
[Windows Azure Website: Uploading/Downloading files over FTP and collecting Diagnostics logs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/avkashchauhan/2012/06/19/windows-azure-website-uploadingdownloading-files-over-ftp-and-collecting-diagnostics-logs/)
You can connect via FTP but it is your Azure credentials and for site maintenance

I assume you are talking about a Web App client without an Azure account (well not your Azure account).

I had a similar question recently and got down voted and closed.

Pretty those ports are just plain not on a Web App and cannot be opened. Pretty sure there is no FTP Service.

Since there is no file structure in Azure (only blobs) FTP just no longer fits.  I suspect you could code a FTP service that works with blobs but still don't think Azure App App would open up 20 and 21.

A got a recommendation to use SAS.

This may help [Using Shared Access Signatures](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1/)

This may help [blob-sas-wcf-and-perfomance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39559020/blob-sas-wcf-and-perfomance)

I really hope I am wrong on this answer
Since a lot of this second hand I am not really sure
I will delete this after the OP has a chance to see it

Comment: Thanks, though from looking at it, it appears I can sync a Dropbox account to the site and upload files that way?

Not sure why anyone downvoted you; that's dumb.  I would upvote if I could.